# Pyside QGraphicsScene event

Tags: python, pyside

I am reading the documentation about QGraphicsScene and View in pyside but I can't find the way to get a signal that warns me when a QGraphicsItem goes beyond the scene, in order to know when I can do something after the item is about to leave the scene. I have to implement a solution by myself or exist a way to do this using Pyside?

Comment: Do you mean "goes beyond the visible part (View)"? Because, `QGraphicsScene` has no bound. It's practically infinite, so items *can't* move beyond the scene.